# switch off windows 10 defender antivirus permanently as it is creating problem to android studio

Tags: windows, android-studio, build.gradle, antivirus

I want to disable the windows 10 defender antivirus permanently or switch off the notifications that I get on switching it off. Also, it should not be turned on after a windows update.

I can switch it off through https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-off-defender-antivirus-protection-in-windows-security-99e6004f-c54c-8509-773c-a4d776b77960

But it shows me constant notifications to turn it on and get turned on automatically after windows updates.

or someone please tell me the method to use the android studio with anti-virus as it shows me warnings and also android studio runs very slow with the antivirus enabled. especially during the build process or when we run the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you follow the method specified in your post, the action is not permanent. (the antivirus will turn itself back on after sometimes)

[image]

You can try disable it via registry. First, open a `Registry Editor`. Next, navigate to `Computer > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Policies > Microsoft > Windows Defender`. Add a key name `DisableAntiSpyware` with type `REG_DWORD` and set its value to `1`. Restart your PC afterwards.

[image]

**Notes**: Advisable to have windows defender turned on unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Can I enable it back if I faced some more problems

Comment: in reference to your advisory

Comment: will deleting the key undo this action?

Comment: Yes, delete this key will enable the antivirus back.